# Find the value $\int_0^{2\pi} (u^2 (re^{i\theta}) - v^2 (re^{i\theta}))d\theta$ for the curve $\vert z \vert =r$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

$f(z) = u(z) + iv(z)$ is a analytic function on $D =\{z  \in \mathbb{C} \vert \Vert z\Vert <1 \}$ with $f(0) = 2+i.$ Find the $\int_0^{2\pi} (u^2 (re^{i\theta}) - v^2 (re^{i\theta}))d\theta$ (Here the $0< r<1$)

I took the $z=re^{i\theta}$ for the substitution. Then

$\int_0^{2\pi} (u^2 (re^{i\theta}) - v^2 (re^{i\theta}))d\theta = \int_{\vert z \vert =r} \frac{u^2(z) - v^2(z)}{iz} dz = \frac{1}{i} Re(\int_{\vert z \vert =r} \frac{{f(z)}^2}{z} dz) $

By Cauchy integral formula, $\int_{\vert z \vert =r} \frac{{f(z)}^2}{z} dz = \frac{1}{i}Re(2\pi i \{f(0)\}^2) = \frac{1}{i}(-8\pi) = 8\pi i$

But the answer is $6\pi$. Would you tell me which point did I missed?

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you are factorizing the $i$ before.

So instead you can write:

$$\text{Re}\left(\frac{1}{i}\int_{|z|=r}\frac{f(z)^2}{z}\right) = \text{Re}  \bigg(2\pi(3+4i)\bigg)= 6\pi.$$

Comment: Does this answer your question?